# Cannot connect to host -1016

Tags: temenos-quantum

Am new in kony. And am trying to connect webservice. Kindly check given below code.

```
var myhttpheaders={"Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"};`enter code here`

   var email = myFrm.textbox212343550452827.text;`enter code here`
   var pwd = myFrm.textbox212343550452828.text;`enter code here`

var inputParamTable =    {   "appID":"NewTestAsync",   
                          "serviceID":"User",   
                          "channel":"rc", 
                          "emailID":email, 
                          "Password":pwd,
                          httpheaders: myhttpheaders,
                          httpconfig:{timeout: 600, method: "post"} };  
try   
{   

var connHandle   = kony.net.invokeServiceAsync(//sample/middleware/MWServlet),inputParamTable, callbackfunction);

}   
catch(err)   
{   
 alert("Error"+err);   
 }  
}
```

So my kony server is kony.net.invokeServiceAsync(//sample/middleware/MWServlet)throwing  error like **1016 cannot connect to host**.

Please any one help me for solve this issue.

Thanks&Regards,

Ramesh babu.K

Answer (score 0):

inputParamTable, callbackfunctionFirstly, the right side of 'connHandle' statement is missing a "(".

Secondly the format for invoking a service call would be : `kony.net.invokeServiceAsync (url,inputParamTable,callback,info)`

You need to enter an actual URL like so :

```
var connHandle = kony.net.invokeServiceAsync("http://www.test.kony.com", 
                                            inputParamTable, callbackfunction);
```

So, Instead of `//sample/middleware/MWServlet`

try to give it like so :

```
kony.net.invokeServiceAsync("http://192.168.x.x:8080/middleware/MWServlet", inputParamTable, callbackfunction);
```

where you replace the `192.168.x.x:8080` with your local kony server IP.

So please check your parameters once again and try.